# Force directory hosting as a Client with index.htm present?

Tags: apache-2.2, directory-listing

I'm asking about the client side.
Is it possible to get a directory listing from an apache if I know listings are allowed but there's a index.htm in this directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove index.htm from the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Comment: I'm not in control of that Server. That's what I meant with client side.

Comment: In that case, no. It would be a pretty bad thing security-wise if the client could control what the server serves in that way.